# How to add Text to TextField

Tags: flutter, dart

How to add Text to TextField widget. I have added the image so that you can understand easily what I am trying to say.

[image]

```dart
TextField(
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0.1),
        isDense: true,
        hintText: "اسمك (اسم صفحتك)",
        fillColor: Colors.black,
    ),
    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
    style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
),
```

Comment: add code for your TextField

Comment: @KirillMatrosov I have updated the question, kindly check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this result with two different ways:

First, using hintText and suffixIcon, and then styling the hint:

```
TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Hint Text',
        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
        suffixIcon: Padding(      //suffixIcon, this way it don't disapear when the TextField is unfocused
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20), //padding to put closer to the line
          child: Text(
            'Right text',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
         ),
       ),
     ),
   ),
```

result:

[image]

Second way, using prefixIcon and suffixIcon:

```
TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
          width: 50,
          height: 10,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.red,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
          child: Text('Text', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
        ),
        suffixIcon: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
          child: Text(
            'Right text',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

result:

[image]

Comment: No i don't need suffix and prefix, already i have added the label text as i mention in image but how do i add the text in the textfield on the right corner.

Answer (score 0):

Use an InputDecoration in the TextField

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Text in TextField',
  ),
),
```

Comment: already i have added the hint text but how do i add the another text  on the left corner in textfield widget.

Comment: @mohammednabil you can style the hint text to stick to the left corner